# monitor kuberntes cluster which created using kops with prometheus running on different vpc

Tags: kubernetes, prometheus, kops, prometheus-operator

I created a kubernetes cluster on aws using kops so it created the certificates on its own. 
so next is to add kubernetes api server in prometheus configuration.
I  used the below prometheus configuration.

```
 - role: node
  api_server: 'https://example.com'
  basic_auth:
    username: 'username'
    password: 'password'
  tls_config:
    ca_file: '/opt/prometheus-2.1.0.linux-amd64/ca.crt'
    server_name: kubernetes
```

It's adding the targets in prometheus but prometheus unable to scrap the targets with the below error.

```
Get https://x.x.x.x:10250/metrics: x509: cannot validate certificate for x.x.x.x because it doesn't contain any IP SANs
```

eventhough i added server_name: kubernetes in the above configuration.
I took kubernetes from the certficate.

```
openssl x509 -text -noout -in ca.crt
```

It has below contents.
   Subject: CN=kubernetes

Comment: If I understand this correctly, prometheus can connect to the API and fetch all the nodes. But it cannot scrape the nodes themselves?

Answer (score -2):

Try with this. for setting up kubernetes cluster using ansible.
This will provision AWS ec2 and will setup cluster. This role includes lots of addons which is sufficient for development cluster
[1]: https://github.com/khann-adill/kubernetes-ansible

Comment: Going for an entirely different way of maintaining a k8s cluster could be a bit overkill for this problem.